# Endpoint with java, where is the session?

Tags: java, web-services, session, endpoint

This is my code on main:

```
Endpoint.publish("http://0.0.0.0:8080/ws/WebServices", new WebServicesImpl());
```

And this is my WebServicesImpl:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "ws.WebServices")
public class WebServicesImpl implements WebServices {

    @Override
    public void recibirTramaPosicionWS(AnObject anobject) {
        AThread ttp  = AThread(anobject);
            ttp.start();
    }
}
```

The web service works without problems, I can access to it and all fine, but I have a big question: can I get the session of my clients, or requests, or something to use in the WebServicesImpl?? I need to implement security in this web service.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see an example here: [How to get session object while working on webservices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076613/how-to-get-session-object-while-working-on-webservices)

normally this is depending on the container you use, but the `@Resource` Annotation gives you some default objects like the `WebserviceContext`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in regular life we don't publish web services like this approach. Its typically done by different api like apache-cxf, axis etc. You can also use different frameworks to expose web services like spring.

Coming to your problem, this is just a program which is listening on a port for http calls. It  should only be used for testing purpose. The "Endpoint" class is a class which ships with jdk bundle. You cannot get session management with this approach. If you want session management, i would suggest to go for real application server and deploy your application on that.

Comment: Thanks, I know that's not the best way to develop an web service app, but I need an interface (not web, a desktop interface) and this is the quick way to do it that I know. If you can help me with another way...